# Pricebox.js Issue Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, catalog, quickview

I'm having an issue with pricebox.js/configurable.js and configurable products.  They are used in quickview and on individual product pages.

The first error I get is a console error calling a method on pricebox.js prior to inititialization.  I was able to work through this, and resolve it, leading to more errors

Second error: Once I got that going, when you select configurable products, the initial price is accurate.  When I fill out the select boxes, however, the price goes haywire.  I'll end up with something like $-49.23, or some other ridiculous and or negative number.

Third error: Once a price gets updated through quickview, every single price on that page becomes updated to that price.  So if I select values for product A, the new price for product A will now show up on product B.

Comment: I have the same error I think. How were you able to work through that? Have you figured out what causes it?

Comment: Hey Jacco, late response here.  'Can't call method on pricebox prior to initialization' is the culprit here.  So in the javascript where it says priceBoxVar.options(stuff,goes,here), you need to update it to: priceBoxVar.priceBox().options(stuff,goes,here). Hopefully this helps

Comment: @JohnSweriduk, can you please share your fix here. Same issue i am struggling with.