# configurable price issue in quickview and list page magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

I'm having an issue with `pricebox.js/configurable.js` and configurable products. They are used in quickview and on individual product pages.

same Issue I can see in this platform in this link
[Pricebox.js Issue Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/168227/pricebox-js-issue-magento-2)

I have updated my configurable.js for this line:

```
priceBoxOptions = $(this.options.priceHolderSelector).priceBox('option').priceConfig || null;
```

as

```
priceBoxOptions = $(this.options.priceHolderSelector).priceBox().priceBox('option', 'openOnFocus', true).priceConfig || null;
```

This has resolved option load issue. but pricing is not showing correct now. Also on change of quick view super attributes options, product list page prices updating as same price.

Can someone help?

Comment: I am also facing the exact scenario..How did u solve this?

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed this bug for our theme, We want to share it with you. You can fix it by update file:
https://github.com/magepow/magento-2-alo-support/blob/master/app/design/frontend/Alothemes/default/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js/configurable.js

Note: Changed Alothemes/default to your theme.

Best Regards,

David of Alo Team